# Selenium WebDriver .getWindowHandles() returns previously closed windows, how can I distinguish these from active windows?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I'm trying to create a function that loops through open windows and switches to a specific one based on the window title. This works for the first few windows, but the site I'm automating utilizes several popup windows that self close on actions such as a "next" button, and those handles seem to continue to be present after the window is closed.

So, when I try to switch to a window to check its title, the script times out because the WebDriver can't switch to a nonexistent window. It doesn't throw a NoSuchWindowException though, which is weird.

Below is my method for traversing windows and switching by title

```
public String switchByTitle(String title)
{
    boolean isPage = false;
    String neededHandle = null;

    while(isPage == false)
    {
        for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
        {
            try 
            {
                //vvv timeout occurs here vvv
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                if (driver.switchTo().window(winHandle).getTitle().equals(title))
                {
                    isPage = true;
                    neededHandle = winHandle;
                    break;
                }
            }   
            catch (NoSuchWindowException e)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return neededHandle;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Not Ideal But I found a Workaround

```
public String switchByTitle(String title)
    {
        boolean isPage = false;
        String neededHandle = null;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

        while(isPage == false)
        {
            for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
            {
                try
                {   
                    //shortened timeout to 5 seconds        
                    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                    if (driver.switchTo().window(winHandle).getTitle().equals(title))
                    {
                        isPage = true;
                        neededHandle = winHandle;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (NoSuchWindowException e)
                {
                    continue;
                }   
                //added timeout exception
                catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        //reset timeout
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return neededHandle;
    }
```

Comment: It likely is not a different window.  Most pop-ups are done in the same window, even though they are modal in nature.  It depends entirely on the DOM, of course, most web applications that do open something outside the existing DOM do so in a new tab, rarely in a new window (browser instance).

Comment: try refreshing the screen before you call getWindowHandls methos.

Comment: @Bill Hileman, it's not a new instance of the browser but it is a new window, with a unique window handle. I have to use the switchTo().window(handle) command in order to switch between them, but when old popups are closed their handles remain, which causes the switchTo() function to time out.

Comment: @Auro Sarma is this a selenium command I'm unaware of or do you mean refresh the browser page? If it's the latter, I can't do that as the popup window is modal.

Comment: Show some of your code, please - in the original post, not as a comment.

Comment: @Bill Hileman I've updated the post with the offending function

Answer (score 0):

Used this as workaround:

```
public String switchByTitle(String title)
    {
        boolean isPage = false;
        String neededHandle = null;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

        while(isPage == false)
        {
            for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
            {
                try
                {   
                    //shortened timeout to 5 seconds        
                    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                    if (driver.switchTo().window(winHandle).getTitle().equals(title))
                    {
                        isPage = true;
                        neededHandle = winHandle;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (NoSuchWindowException e)
                {
                    continue;
                }   
                //added timeout exception
                catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        //reset timeout
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return neededHandle;
    }
```